# How to fix TypeError when using `scipy.optimize.fsolve`?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to find the roots of a function `F(f)` while varrying the values of a parameter `x` by using `scipy.optimize.fsolve`. Here is the code:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

def F(f,*x):
    return np.cosh(((x-1)/(x+1))*(np.log(2)/f))-0.5*np.exp(np.log(2)/f)

x = np.logspace(0,3,100)
y = np.arange(x.size)

for i in range(x.size):
    y = fsolve(F, 0.5, args = x[i])
```

The code above returns a:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

The funny thing is that this same code works when I change `F(f,x)` to a simple function, there is no `TypeError`

```
def F(f,*x):
   return (2*np.cos(f)-f)*x

x = np.logspace(0,3,100)
y = np.arange(x.size)

for i in range(x.size):
    y = fsolver(F, 0.5, args=x[i])
```

What is it about the first function that causes a type error where as the second function is just fine?

Comment: In these `scipy` functions, the `args` parameter is supposed to be a `tuple`, eg `args=(x[i],)`.  The comma matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `*` in the definition of `F`.

Since you use variable parameter list `*x`, the `x` that `F` received is actually a tuple, and `np.cosh(((x-1)/(x+1)))` operation doest not support tuple.